# Defining a Torus class

Tags: haskell

I would like to define a `Torus` class representing 2D arrays that wrap around at borders. For example, accessing the array with an index beyond the size of the corresponding dimension should return the element at position `i mod arraysize`. My class should thus only need to define a `get` method as such:

```
class Torus a where
    get :: a -> Int -> Int -> b
```

This definition is imprecise. `a` is supposed to be a 2D array and `b` should be the type contained in the array. How can I express this?

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't this just a circular list of circular lists?

Comment: @Sarah but implementing it this way will make the program slower than it could be with vectors for example.

Comment: Do you come from an OO background? This does not look like a job for a typeclass; rather an abstract data type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you were only looking for the types in the class:

```
class Torus t where
    get :: t a -> Int -> Int -> a
```

Or did you look for an appropriate instance?

Answer (score 8):

You can also use functional dependencies or type families in case you want to have something more sophisticated than simple `t :: * -> *` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Torus t v | t -> v where
    get :: t -> Int -> Int -> v

instance Torus (Vector a) a where
    get = ...
```

or

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Torus t where
    type Element t
    get :: t -> Int -> Int -> Element t

instance Torus (Vector a) where
    type Element (Vector a) = a
    get = ...
```

This requires some GHC extensions though.

Comment: Just curious: What are cases where you would need this?

Comment: In general case collection type can be something more complex than `* -> *`-kinded type. For example, a function of type `Int -> Int -> a` can also be viewed as a 2d matrix, and you cannot make it a sound instance of needed type class without FDs/TFs. You can read GHC documentation on the background of FDs: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#id3176364 . Associated types do the same job, so this applies to them too.